# get nearest previous h2 which as href using webdriver io browser

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io, wdio

```
<h2><a href="link1"></a></h2>
<p></p>
<table></table>
<h2></h2>
<table><tbody><tr class="failure"><td>404</td></tr></tbody</table>
<h2></h2>
<table></table>
<h2></h2>
<table></table>
<h2></h2>
<table></table>
<h2><a href="link2"></a></h2>
<p></p>
<table></table>
<h2></h2>
<table></table>
<h2></h2>
<table></table>
<h2></h2>
<table><tbody><tr class="failure"><td>missing goto in shop link</td></tr></tbody</table>
<h2></h2>
<table></table>
<h2><a href="link2"></a></h2>
<p></p>
<table></table>
<h2></h2>
<table><tbody><tr><td>pass</td></tr></tbody</table>
<h2></h2>
<table></table>
```

trying to get following

[
cell: 404,
href: link1
]

[
cell:missing goto in shop link,
href: link2
]

- For each  element, the code finds all 
  elements with the class "failure" and stores them in the failureRows
  array.
- For each  element found in failureRows, the code extracts
  the text of each  element and stores them in the cells array
  using the map function.
- The code then finds the previous  element
  that contains an  element and extracts the href attribute of the
   element using the getAttribute function.

I am having issue with getting nearest previous href from h2 tag

this is not working:

```
const aTag = await table.$("preceding-sibling::h2").$('a[href]')
      hrefValue = await aTag.getAttribute('href');
```